# Azure DevOps Pipeline local MariaDB

Tags: azure-devops, mariadb, github-actions, pipeline, cicd

I want to migrate my github action pipeline to azure devops, unfortunally i wasn't able to find an alternative to the github action "ankane/setup-mariadb@v1".
For my pipline I need to create a local mariadb with a database loaded from a .sql file.
I also need to create a user for that database.
This was my code in my github pipeline:

```
    - name: Installing MariaDB
      uses: ankane/setup-mariadb@v1
      with:
        mariadb-version: ${{ matrix.mariadb-version }}
        database: DatabaseName
    - name: Creating MariaDB User
      run: |
        sudo mysql -D DatabaseName -e "CREATE USER 'Username'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';"
        sudo mysql -D DatabaseName -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DatabaseName.* TO 'Username'@localhost;"
        sudo mysql -D DatabaseName -e "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
    - name: Importing Database
      run: |
        sudo mysql -D DatabaseName < ./test/database.sql
```

Does anybody know if there is a alternative for azure devops pipelines?

Cheers,

Comment: If you are looking for a similar task, the answer is NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anybody know if there is a alternative for azure devops
> pipelines?

If the alternative you mentioned means some tasks in Azure DevOps pipeline can do the similar thing as 'ankane/setup-mariadb@v1' in GitHub, **then the answer is NO.**

DevOps doesn't have a 'build_in' task like this, even the marketplace also doesn't have a extension to do this.

So you have two ways:

1, If your pipeline based on [Microsoft hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#microsoft-hosted-agents), everything should be set up via command:

[How to Install and Start Using MariaDB on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.cherryservers.com/blog/how-to-install-and-start-using-mariadb-on-ubuntu-20-04)

2, If your pipeline based on [self hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install), then you can 'set up' the environment(MariaDB) before start the pipeline. And then use it in your DevOps pipeline.